# Using Regular Expression in Delphi to search ADOQuery joined to Ms Access

Tags: regex, delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe5

I want to Search an Access Database By Regular Expression.
I can use Regexp within Ms Access itself. But i want to use ADOQuery in Delphi XE5.

Sample query from inside Access

```sql
SELECT 
  MyTable.[1] AS Expr1, 
  RegExp([1],"ض[^A-Za-z0-9_]*َ[^A-Za-z0-9_]*ر[^A-Za-z0-9_]*ب[^A-Za-z0-9_]*",True) AS Exp2 
FROM MyTable1
```

How ADOQuery can Apply Regular Expression?

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Do you have a query already?

Comment: yes, like this:SELECT MyTable.[1] AS Expr1, RegExp([1],"ض[^A-Za-z0-9_]*َ[^A-Za-z0-9_]*ر[^A-Za-z0-9_]*ب[^A-Za-z0-9_]*",True) AS Exp2
FROM MyTable1;

Comment: it works fine in access because Regexp() is a module in it.

Comment: Did you already try to pass that statement via ADOQuery?

Comment: yes, by ADOQuery in delphi.

Comment: Outside of MS Access, the best you can do, AFAIK, is LIKE and NOT LIKE, for example `Not Like "[a-v]*"`

Comment: Good idea for simple cases, but regexp has features not supported in Access. For example /s /d etc